# How many connected peers should I expect on my running node?

Tags: node, baker, kiln, peers

I have been running a tezos node for a few days, I usually see between 39 to 45 peers connected.

How many connected peers should I expect to be connected to my node while syncing on the mainnet? How many peers after the node is bootstrapped?

Does the number of peers depends on resources such as CPU or network?
Any way to check if I have reached some bottleneck?

[image: node status]

I have the following related open ports on my server.
but I hasn't sure if they needed to be open on my firewall as well.

```
tcp   LISTEN   0        128     0.0.0.0:8000                                             0.0.0.0:*                       users:(("tezos-node",pid=12811,fd=30),("mainnet-tezos-n",pid=12806,fd=30),("backend",pid=990,fd=30))
tcp   LISTEN   0        128     [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:8733                                                   *:*                       users:(("mainnet-tezos-n",pid=12806,fd=28))                                    
tcp   LISTEN   0        20      [::ffff:0.0.0.0]:9733                                                   *:*                       users:(("tezos-node",pid=12811,fd=7),("mainnet-teos-n",pid=12806,fd=28))
```

I have opened the following port ranges 8732-8735 and 9732-9735 to all internet 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 on my firewall.

it went up to 61, but still far from hundreds. I'm not sure if the bump from 45 to 61 is related

I tried to be looking for a config file that could be relevant
but scanning through the `dpkg -L kiln` output, I did not find any other files than those two, which are almost empty.

```
ubuntu@baker:~$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-kiln-userns.conf
kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
ubuntu@baker:~$ cat /etc/kiln/args 
KILNARGS=
ubuntu@baker:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure with regards to Kiln, but our node (non-kiln) averages 250-300 connected peers. The number of peers is directly configured within the tezos-node config file. Perhaps in Kiln there is some way to modify that config file?

Comment: I have not found any relevant config files

Comment: Make sure 9732 is not blocked by iptables/ufw and make sure your router is forwarding that port to the computer running the tezos-node

Answer (score 2):

Number of peers should be in the hundreds.

Kiln runs a node with default net-addr port 9732. Check that this port 9732 is open on your kiln server. You may need to configure your networking router to port forward to your kiln server as well.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if I should open those ports on my firewall. 8732 as well, both?

Comment: oh, I know for sure they were on 8732,9732 at first, but after a reboot, it seems they have changed to 8733,9733 something to keep in mind..

Comment: Do not open 8732 to the world. That is the RPC-API port and should be protected. 9733 and 8733 are both Dune ports. Tezos uses 9732/8732.